# Feature extraction from music segments

Tags: time-series, python, feature-selection, feature-engineering, musical-data-analysis

I'm doing a project on music mood classification and using the Million Song Dataset.

I have two features `Segments_Timbre` and `Segments_Pitches` that I would like to analyze. Here is some information about these: https://web.archive.org/web/20161203075937/http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/millionsong/pages/example-track-description

`Segments_Timbre` contains multidimensional arrays and the shapes vary for each song. For e.g, in one song it may (965, 12) while for another it could be (679, 12). This is an MFCC like feature.

`Segments_Pitches` is similar and contains chroma features for each segment.

My questions are:

1. Can these two be called time series data?
2. If this is time series data, is segment aggregation (taking average and standard deviation of each segment) enough? I assume this would cause a loss of information.
3. How do I extract features from these two columns such that they can be used in SVMs, Random Forests and other classifiers?
4. What sort of time series based feature extraction should I do?
5. Is PCA useful here in anyway? The pitch and timbre features are quite large.

Comment: It sounds like time series data to me. However, if your goal is "music mood classification" I am not sure if you want to do much with this. For example, "major vs. minor key" might not need this, while "fast vs. slow tempo" may be extractable without doing in-depth analysis. Is this a clustering problem or a classification one? (i.e. do you have labeled data, where each song has a "mood" pre-assigned?)

Comment: Yes, I have Key and Tempo as features too. Is it not important to use Timbre and Pitch for mood analysis? I'm working with very little knowledge of music here. It's a classification problem. I labeled over a 1000 songs by hand as 'happy' or 'sad'.

Comment: Well, if it is you who labeled the songs, then "is it not important ..." probably depends on how subtle your tastes are! Actually, with only a binary mood classification, your problem is simpler that I was thinking. Anyway, I was not saying Timbre and Pitch are necessarily unimportant, but rather how important is it to treat them as time series. My comment was more along the lines of "perhaps a bulk histogram of Pitch could indicate key", or "a bulk histogram of first differences in Timbre could perhaps indicate tempo". If you wanted style, or details like melody, more might be needed.

Comment: Yeah, I made a conscious effort to label based on audio features than just lyrics and I would like to think my tastes are quite subtle. :) It is indeed a problem that sounds simple but I peak at about 66% accuracy and I am wondering if there's anything I can do with timbre & pitch to improve on that. I'm also generally interested in knowing how others would deal with those two in other types of tasks.

Comment: I do not have experience in this area (aside from e.g. using Pandora). You might check around [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/msdchallenge/) to see "what others have done"? (same data, different task).

Comment: Thanks, I had looked around on the forums there but they weren't really using audio features.